# Prevent local changes getting pushed in Git

Tags: git, git-push

I have cloned a repository and the `master` branch in my repo is tracking `origin/master`. I created a `work` branch and changed some config files specific to my dev machine to make the app work.

My normal workflow will be to switch to `master` branch, merge changes made in `work` branch and `push` those changes upstream. The problem is that i don't want my specific chnages to get pushed. When i merge my `work` branch into `master` those changes are merged also.

The only solution I've found so far is not to commit those changes in `work` but that's not a satisfactory solution.

Comment: Such config files should not be in the repository at all--remove them.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007397/howto-prevent-git-from-pushing-changes-to-some-files

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/655243/ignore-modified-but-not-committed-files-in-git

Comment: possible duplicate of [Committing Machine Specific Configuration Files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396617/committing-machine-specific-configuration-files)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

If you want to prevent committing (therefore also pushing) these local config files, you could use [git update-index --assume-unchanged](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/18/temporarily-ignoring-files.html). Files marked with this flag will be assumed to never change (until you reset the flag with --no-assume-unchanged)

Comment: What happens with those config files when you checkout another branch?

Comment: @pomber AFAIK they remain untouched by git.

Comment: This works only for a single repository strategy and not pushable. You still can not propagate that change to the remote repository with a commit. You have to use direct console access to the remote repository to raise the flag.

Answer (score 8):

If the files are not already being tracked, you can add them to a .gitignore file to your local repository, otherwise you will need to use `git update-index --assume-unchanged` like Mauricio said.

Following is more information about .gitignore files:

http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Answer (score 7):

One way to solve this is to "cherry-pick" each change from your work branch into master before you push upstream. I've used a technique where I include a word like NOCOMMIT into the commit message for local changes only, and then use a shell script something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

BRANCH=`git branch | grep ^\\* | cut -d' ' -f2`
if [ $BRANCH != "master" ]; then
  echo "$0: Current branch is not master"
  exit 1
fi

git log --pretty=oneline work...master | grep -v -E '(NOCOMMIT|DEBUG):' | cut -d' ' -f1 | tac | xargs -l git cherry-pick
```

This cherry-picks each change that is *not* marked with NOCOMMIT (or DEBUG) into the master branch.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a .gitignore file and add all your config file inside the .gitignore file.

Once your .gitignore file is ready you might need to removed your config files from the Cache

Here's the command:

```
(Assume you use linux)
vi .gitignore
//Add all your config file inside

//run the following command to remove your config file from GIT cache if your config files is already track by GIT

git rm --cached myconfig.php
```