# git: ignoring a file which *is* version controlled

Tags: git

A `.gitignore` file allows to ignore files from version controlling them at all.

We have a different situation: we want to place in the repository some configuration files, that need to be changed on per-machine basis (db access info for instance).

We do want to distribute them, as placeholders, so we include them into the repository.
However, later we want any changes to them to be ignored, for all developers.

Is there a way to do it?

*Note:*

The question [Git: Ignoring Version-Controlled Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633681/git-ignoring-version-controlled-files) is actually the same. However, none of the answers answered the question, including the accepted one.

*Edit:*

- Is there a way to do  --assume-unchanged to a pattern rather than a single file?
- Is there a way to propagate this command to the repositories of other developers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent local changes to get pushed in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173726/prevent-local-changes-to-get-pushed-in-git)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743770/git-collaboration-how-to-manage-configuration-files, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396617/git-committing-machine-specific-configuration-files

Comment: Possible duplicate of probably all of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[git]+%2Bassume-unchanged

Comment: All this about duplicates said, I *completely* agree with mathepic: the solution isn't to work around version control, the solution is to give your program the ability to choose between configurations.

Answer (score 47):

I define the following aliases in my `.gitconfig` file:

```
[alias]
  ignore = update-index --assume-unchanged
  unignore = update-index --no-assume-unchanged
```

That should do exactly what you want: running `git ignore some-file` will treat the file as unchanged no matter what you do to it, until you run `git unignore some-file`.

Comment: Is there no way to ignore whole directories?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12288212/git-update-index-assume-unchanged-on-directory: `git ls-files -z path/to/directory | xargs -0 git ignore`

Answer (score 3):

I know this kind of dodges the issue, but I would have a ".defaults" file for each, and then change this. This helps with the configuration energy anyway - what if someone who has a custom configuration wants to change the defaults?

Don't ignore the .defaults, ignore the actual thing. Maybe have a script that copies the .defaults to the regular ones if they don't already exist.