# git update-index --assume-unchanged on directory

Tags: git, command-line, pipe

git 1.7.12

I want to mark all files below a given directory as assume-unchanged.

1. `git update-index --assume-unchanged dir/` gives "Ignoring path."
2. `git update-index --assume-unchanged dir/*` quickly fails because it will encounter files which are not being tracked, hence it gives "fatal: Unable to mark file" and quits.
3. Try generating a list of files to mark.  `cd` into the desired directory and then run `git ls-files | tr '\n' ' ' | git update-index --assume-unchanged`.  This produces no error message, but it does not successfully mark the files.  The first portion of the command, `git ls-files | tr '\n' ' '`, correctly produces a space delimited list of all the files I want to mark.  If I copy and paste the output of that command onto the command-line, then the `git update-index` command works.  What is not working with the pipes?

No, it is not sufficient for me to add `dir` to .gitignore.  I need these files to be in the repository, but undesired changes will be made locally that need to be ignored so that users can do pulls.

Comment: You mispelled *--assume-uncha**n**ged*

Comment: @AdamMudianto fixed

Answer (score 218, accepted):

`git update-index` wants the file names on its command line, not on its standard input.

### Step 1:

`cd` into the folder you want to assume is unchanged

### Step 2:

You can do either this:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged $(git ls-files | tr '\n' ' ')
```

or

```
git ls-files | tr '\n' ' ' | xargs git update-index --assume-unchanged
```

Although, with either case, file names with spaces will be problematic. If you have those, you can use this:

```
git ls-files -z | xargs -0 git update-index --assume-unchanged
```

Edit: incorporated input from @MatthewScharley regarding `git ls-files -z`.

#### Windows Commands

> **Note:** If you're on windows, use *Git Bash* to run these commands

Comment: FYI, that ` | tr '\n' ' '` bit is unnecessary.

Comment: @VáclavSlavík You're right... can't remember why I put that in, other than for symmetry with the `tr '\n' '\0'` case (in which case it is needed)...

Comment: @twalberg: You could just use `git ls-files -z`

Comment: @twalberg How to undo this command "git ls-files -z | xargs -0 git update-index --assume-unchanged"

Comment: @MohamedHussain `git ls-files -z | xargs -0 git update-index --no-assume-unchanged`, I would think...

Comment: `git ls-files -z | git update-index -z --stdin` is cleaner.

Comment: This does not seem to work in `git version 2.33.0` for untracked files inside folders.

Comment: @MichaelTrouw Asker specifically stated `git` version 1.7.2. Changes made to `git` behavior between 1.7.2 and 2.33.0 do not invalidate this answer.

Answer (score 31):

The `find` command from GNU Findutils has a `-exec` option which removes most of the hassle of using `xargs`, although its syntax is a little special. It does however deal perfectly with filenames with spaces.

This command will get git to assume all files in and under the listed directory are unchanged:

```
find path/to/dir -type f -exec git update-index --assume-unchanged '{}' \;
```

Find takes every argument after `-exec` until `;` (which you have to escape lest your shell eats it) and runs it once for each file found, while replacing `{}` (again, single quoted so your shell won't eat it) with the found file's name.

Using `find`'s  matching criteria (maximum recursion depth, whether the match is a file or is a directory, whether the filename matches an expression) and `-exec` you can do all sort of powerful things.

Not sure about other implementations of the `find` command. YMMV.

Comment: [`-exec` is a standard option](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html). You can also `-exec git update-index --assume-unchanged {} +` (also defined by the standard) which passes multiple file names to the command at once, reducing the number of times the git command is invoked.

Comment: The disadvantage of the `-exec git update-index --assume-unchanged {} +` is that if one file fails they all will, so it won't work if there are tracked and untracked files in the directory

Comment: Nice one bro...

Answer (score 31):

Add the directory name to `.git/info/exclude`.  This works for untracked files.

Comment: This work great! Did you know if this work with files too?

Comment: But this doesn't push the untracked files github! is there any possible way to  just ignore them from the records but actually keeping them in the repos!?

Answer (score 3):

Yeap,

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged
```

works with files only, not with directories.
I think, one of faster ways:

```
cd dir
ls | xargs -l git update-index --assume-unchanged
```

Comment: Instead of using `cd`, you can pass the dir as a final argument: `git ls-files -- $DIR | xargs -l git update-index --assume-unchanged -- $DIR`.