# Remove files from local git but not from remote

Tags: git

I need to delete a directory of tracked files from my local working directory but not from the remote git server.

I tried `git rm --cached` but it seems like it will commit those changes to the server. I want the files to remain tracked on the server.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with `git rm` (with or without `--cached`) is that it would stage the deletion of the directory in your local index, making it a possible candidate for a commit (which can be pushed by mistake, deleting the directory in the upstream repo as well)

You could try, within your directory:

```
  git ls-files | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 git update-index --assume-unchanged
```

(see more at "[`git update-index --assume-unchanged` on directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12288918/6309)"), and then a simple *non-git* command:

```
  rm -Rf yourDirectory
```

Your git repo should ignore the deletion, and it has no effect on the index.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to ignore the files in your local git repo.

exclude them in
`.git/info/exclude`