# Git commit changes in folder from .gitignore once

Tags: git, github, gitignore

is it possible to have a folder ignored by git even if sometimes this folder is committed?

The background is that in open source projects I don't want others to commit the `dist/` folder, however when I build a new version I need to obviously commit the `dist/` folder. Is there a solution to this "problem"?

Thanks

Comment: Not a particularly clean solution, but you could commit `dist/`, and then just have every use assume-unchanged on it when they commit, such that no changes would come in when you don't want them (q.v. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12288212/git-update-index-assume-unchanged-on-directory)).

Answer (score -2):

Even if a file is listed in `.gitignore`, you can use `git add -f [file]` to tell git to actually add it to your next commit.

Putting `dist/` in your `.gitignore` is a way to avoid casual add + commit, and which would still allow you to commit the content when needed.