# Git assume unchanged on a directory not working

Tags: git

I have a fairly large react project and there are certain folders that I want to keep on my local but don't want to push to the repo. For instance

```
app/backend/public/vendor/backpack
```

I've tried the solution here: [git update-index --assume-unchanged on directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12288212/git-update-index-assume-unchanged-on-directory)

Even after trying that, if I

```
git add .
```

It will still add all of the files in that directory. My .gitignore looks like this

```
/backend/public/vendor/*
```

No matter what I try, it keeps adding all of those files.

How can I not include a directory in git commit? I'm using the latest version of Git on Windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git should probably apologize for being confusing here, but Git never apologizes.

1. The "assume unchanged" and "skip worktree" flags are only for *files that Git already knows about* (files that are *tracked*).
2. Listing names or patterns in `.gitignore` is only meaningful for *files that are not tracked*.
3. The word *track*, in Git, is overused: it means several different things.

To explain all this, we must carefully define what, precisely, *tracked* means in Git, in this context.  But to do so requires that we look at Git's *index*, because the precise definition of a *tracked file* is *a file that is listed in Git's index*.  So unless you know what the index is, none of this will make any sense anyway.

#### Defining Git's index

You have probably already seen that a Git repository contains—in fact, is mostly made up of—commits.  A *commit* saves a complete snapshot of some source file(s), along with some extra information about the commit itself: who made it, when, and so on.  Commits are not changes!  Instead, commits carry a *previous* or *parent commit* ID, and if you ask Git to show you a commit, Git will extract both the commit itself, *and* its parent, and then *compare* the parent to the commit.  Whatever is *different*, Git will show you that difference.  This means that `git show <hash>` shows a set of changes, but in fact, the `<hash>` identifies a snapshot.

(The commits are identified by those big ugly hash IDs that you have no doubt also seen.  These appear random, but actually they are cryptographic checksums of the entire contents of each commit.  They are not very useful for humans to work with, though, so we tend to use branch names to identify the *most recent* commit in the branch.)

The files frozen inside Git commits are in a special, read-only, compressed format, useful only to Git itself.  This means that in order to *use* the files, Git has to unfreeze and de-compress the files, turning them into their normal useful-on-the-computer form.  This is your *work-tree* (or *working tree* or any variation on these words), where you do your work.

If Git were like other version control systems, it might stop there, with just the commits (frozen and Git-only) and work-tree (unfrozen, useful to everyone).  But Git is not like other version control systems.  Instead, Git inserts an intermediate location, which Git variously calls the *index*, the *staging area*, or the *cache* (depending on who / what part of Git is doing the calling).

Files in the index are stored in the same Git-only format as in commits, but when they are in the index, they are unfrozen.  The `git checkout` process essentially copies files *from* the frozen commit, *to* the index (unfreezing only), and then to the work-tree (uncompressing and making useful-format).

Why does this index even exist and require that you be aware of it?  For a complete answer, you'd have to ask Linus Torvalds, but we can point out several things that it does:

- It makes new commits lightning-fast.  Git makes new commits by freezing the index contents.  This is *much* faster than plodding through the work-tree, re-compressing every file.  The files that are in the index are already in the special compressed Git-only form, so `git commit` just has to freeze those copies.
- It gives us (and Git) a way to decide which work-tree files are *tracked* and which are *untracked*.

**A tracked file is one that has a copy in the index.**  That's all there is to it, but that's crucial, because as we just saw, Git makes *new* commits from whatever is in the index:

- Running `git add` copies a file from the work-tree into the index.  If there was a copy in the index before, this overwrites the old copy with the new one from the work-tree.  If there *wasn't* a copy before, now there is.  That file, in the form just copied into the index, will go into the *next* commit you make.
- Running `git rm` removes a file from the index (and the work-tree).  If there was a copy in the index before, now there isn't.  The file *won't* be in the next commit you make.

It's not easy to see the contents of the index directly.  (There is one command—`git ls-files`—that will show it, but that particular command is mostly aimed at debugging and writing tools, not for everyday use.)  Instead, the `git status` command shows you what's *different* in the index.  Specifically, it runs two comparisons:

- First, `git status` compares the current commit to the index.  Whatever is *different*, `git status` calls *staged for commit*.  This includes files that are new in the index, removed from the index, or just different in the index from their `HEAD`-commit version.
- Then, `git status` compares the index to the work-tree.  Whatever is *different*, `git status` calls *not staged for commit*.  This includes files that are in the index but not the work-tree or vice versa, and of course files that are in both but are different.

#### Now we can define `assume-unchanged`, `skip-worktree`, and `.gitignore`

Now that we have a good idea what it means for a file to be in the index, so that *that particular copy* of the file goes into the next commit—or to *not* be in the index, so that it *isn't* in the next commit—we can look at what these various options mean and do.

If a file *isn't* in the index, but *is* in the work-tree, `git status` will complain at you during the second comparison.  It will tell you: *Hey, this file is in the work-tree, maybe you should add it to the index.*  If you *don't* want `git status` to complain about the untracked file, you can list the file in `.gitignore`.

This listing *only affects untracked files*.  If the file is already in the index—however it got there, whether that's from a commit or from you doing `git add` on it—then the file is already tracked.  Listing the file in `.gitignore` will have no effect.

If the file *is* in the index *and* you've changed the work-tree copy, `git status` will check on it, and tell you that the work-tree version is modified and maybe you should copy the update into the index, so that the *updated* version goes into the next commit.  This is where `assume-unchanged` and `skip-worktree` come in: with either bit set, `git status` will assume that the work-tree copy is not changed, or skip over it (or both) and not complain about it.

The `git add` command obeys similar rules: if the file *isn't* in the index (but is in the work-tree) and you use an en-masse "add all the files" command, `git add` will *not* add files that are both untracked and ignored.  It will also *not* add files that are tracked but marked to be unchanged-or-skipped.  So the untracked-and-ignored file won't become tracked and won't be in the next commit; and the tracked but skipped-over file won't be *updated*, so that the next commit will continue to use the old stale index copy.

#### Directories are a little weird

Git never stores *directories* (or "folders" if you prefer that word) in commits at all.  Git only stores *files*.  The index only contains files,<sup>1</sup> and only the index entry itself has the assume-unchanged and skip-worktree bits, so you can't set this for a directory, you have to set it for all the tracked files within the directory.

The `.gitignore` file, however, has a special feature, to speed up `git status`.  It turns out that searching through the work-tree is usually the slowest part of everything (which is probably why the index exists at all).  So, if you list a directory name in `.gitignore` *and* there are no files *within* that directory already in the index, Git takes a shortcut, and does not bother looking inside that directory at all.

This means that if none of the files `dir/*` are currently tracked, and you list `dir` in your `.gitignore`, `git status` and `git add .` will never look *inside* `dir` to find any of those files, so it will never add them and will never complain about them being untracked.  Hence, listing a directory in `.gitignore` *can* make Git not include any of the files within the directory.  But once you have tracked at least one file inside the directory, Git feels obligated to scan through the directory anyway, so this doesn't always have this effect.

It's all a little confusing and in extreme cases, you may want to use `git check-ignore -v` or even `git ls-files --stage --debug` to find out which rule(s), if any, are ignoring some file(s) or exactly what's in the index, including the assume-unchanged and skip-worktree flags.  But this mostly does work, and fairly well, in practice.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, the index can store some directory information, especially when using the *untracked cache*.  However, `git ls-files` doesn't show any of this, at least currently, even under `--debug`.

Answer (score 0):

Because the files have already been commited to git, you will have to do the following:

**Step 1**
Delete file from the repository but keep it onto your local disk.

```
git rm --cached [directory/file]
```

Warning: **Do not forget to use `--cached` option for the rm command**. It means that the file will be removed from the repository but it will remain on your local workspace. Without `cached` it will delete from both places. Take care.

**Step 2**
Reload the .gitignore. This means you should put again the [directory/file] inside .gitignore. This step may not be necessary, but it is recommended.

**Step 3**
Commit the changes to git.

```
git commit -m “Ignored the file”
```

Hope this helps, for further reference please read the information at the following link:

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/gitignore

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed:-**
Well sometimes we update our vendor directory on local and that shows a lot if of files deleted and modified. However, you can use this command for any directory in your application.

Go to the vendor directory & run this command:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged $(git ls-files | tr '\n' ' ')
```