# How to avoid symlink destroy in automatic pull requests?

Tags: laravel, git, gitignore, symlink

I have a Laravel project in a Homestead Vagrant environment over Windows 10.
I'm deploying the project to an Apache hosting service. For Laravel storage to work I create a link using `php artisan storage:link`, that creates a link in `/public` called storage with points to `/storage/app/public`.
Each time I push changes to my origin master repository, the hosting automatically does a pull origin master for my project and when it happens the storage link changes to a directory. After that any uploaded photos are not found by the server and I have to delete the `/public/storage` directory to recreate the symlink.

I've created a `.gitignore` file in the public directory to avoid Git from changing anything for the link.

`/public/.gitignore`

```
storage 
!.gitignore
```

I expect the link remain intact each time Git pull takes place automatically in the server.

Answer (score 1):

Since the public/storage folder has tracked content, ignoring it won't have any effect.

That would work for a file:

```
 git update-index --skip-worktree -- afile
```

That should resists a `git pull`.
But you want to [ignore a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12288918/6309) and that is not trivial.
It is best if you make sure storage is *not* tracked (versioned) in your repository in the first place.

The [OP Ricardo Becerra Enríquez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11741700/ricardo-becerra-enr%C3%ADquez) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56895509/how-to-avoid-symlink-destroy-in-automatic-pull-requests/56896739#comment101323480_56896739):

> I contacted the hosting support and they told me that I should ignore the storage link and create the links wherever I need.
>
> So I deleted the storage link that was already on Git, then pushed the changes, pulled again, created the link in the production and now it's working.

Comment: `/public/storage` is not a folder, is a link to the folder `/storage/app/public`

Comment: @RicardoBecerraEnríquez What version of Git for Windows are you using? The symklink should be preserved/restored, instead of being converted to a folder.

Comment: I have version 2.18.0.windows.1 in my development environment and version 2.0.0 in the production environment.

Comment: @RicardoBecerraEnríquez If the production environment is a Windows with Git 2.0, I am not surprised. Any chance to test that with a Git 2.22?

Comment: Hi VonC, I contacted the hosting support and they told me that I should ignore the storage link and create the links whereever I need, so I deleted the storage link that was already on Git, then pushed the changes, pulled again, created the link in the production and now it's working.

Comment: @RicardoBecerraEnríquez Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.