# Ignore deleted files in git?

Tags: git, delete-file

Is it possible to ignore deleted files in git? git update-index --assume-unchanged allows me to ignore modifications, but it still tracks deletions.

(This is similar, but I couldn't find where "John Doe" restated his question: [Ignore modified (but not committed) files in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655243/ignore-modified-but-not-committed-files-in-git))

Comment: It seems odd to me to be tracking files that you don't actually want... but I guess you have your reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to ignore the "delete" status, I would:

- not remove the directory and those files in it
- split the [Git repo in two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository), effectively detaching the subdirectory to be removed into a separate Git repository.
- go on with the main Git repo.

Note: that may not be compatible with a Git repo currently synchronized with a SVN one.

Comment: Yeah, my repo is sync'd with a perforce dir.

Answer (score 2):

The following stops will surely solve your problem:

1. Ensure that all deleted files are not staged to commit.
   *If they are staged, to unstage them you can simply do* `git reset`
2. After this step, run the following command

```
    git ls-files --deleted -z | git update-index --assume-unchanged -z --stdin
```

**Note:** The first command. `git ls-files --deleted -z`, lists all the deleted files as a string. Then it takes that as the input to the second command.