# Git ignore deleted files

Tags: git, delete-file, ignore

I have a website project that has more than 50,000 unimportant files (to development) in some directories.

```
/website.com/files/1.txt
/website.com/files/2.txt
/website.com/files/3.txt
/website.com/files/etc.txt
```

The stuff in /files is already in the repo. I want to delete all the files in /files on my local copy but I want git to ignore it so it doesn't delete them when I do a pull on the web server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok Ive found a solution. Simply create a new repo in the sub directories and the parent repo will ignore them.

Comment: that will work, but it's not ideal to end up with a bunch of branches/repos in multiple projects.  going forward could become a pain as your project list gets larger.  I do recommend becoming a bit more familiar with `.gitignore` and the index management tools.  There's a decent tutorial in my answer above.  It really is fairly easy once you try it once...

Comment: @MaurerPower, while I appreciate your descriptive answer, `git rm --cached` doesn't fit my requirements. For example if I use that command, then commit and push. When I pull to another server it will still delete the files from that server, even though it did not delete them from the original server. I did a litte test, here are my results: http://pastebin.com/5X0t1KGs

Answer (score 16):

Ignoring a whole directory didn't work. I had to do this:

```
for i in `git status | grep deleted | awk '{print $3}'`; do git update-index --assume-unchanged $i; done
```

Comment: I needed to change `$3` to `$2` git version 2.3.2

Answer (score 12):

The code below works on deleted as well as modified files to ignore it when you do a *git status*.

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged dir-im-removing/
```

or a specific file

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged config/database.yml
```

[Ignore modified (but not committed) files in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655243/ignore-modified-but-not-committed-files-in-git/761116#761116)

**Beware: The suggestion above for deleted files when you do a "*git commit -am* " includes the deleted file!**

A solution that would work for me is to instead of deleting the file, just make it's content blank. This is what I used to mute a .htaccess file.

Answer (score 3):

Creating a sub-repo is one solution, but you should make that sub-repo a **[submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979167/git-submodule-update/1979194#1979194)**.

That way:

- you keep a link between your normal content and that 'files' content
- if the 'files' content evolves one day, you can register its evolution in the main repo
- you can checkout your main repo without " `git submodule update` " (that is without filling the '`files`' content
- on deployment, a  `git submodule update` after the  `git submodule init` will be enough to get back the right version of the '`files`' content.

Answer (score 1):

To commit only added / modified files (and NOT removed ones) do:

```
git add . --ignore-removal
git commit -m "commit message"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in `git status | grep deleted | awk '{print $2}'`; do git update-index --assume-unchanged $i; done
```

works with git 2.25.1

if you encounter this issue:

> fatal: Unable to mark file PATH/TO/FILE

check there is no space in the file path and use quotes instead

Answer (score 0):

As @dave1010 pointed out, you have to mark each individual file.
If you don't have `awk` and `bash`, such as for Windows, you can use the following Perl script:

```
foreach (split("\n",`git status`)) {
  if (/^\s+deleted:\s+(.+)$/) {
    `git update-index --assume-unchanged $1`;}}
```

Any Perl for Windows such as Strawberry Perl, works. You can also write a PowerShell script for Windows, but Perl is universal.