# Git ignore locally deleted folder

Tags: git, ignore

I have a Ruby on Rails application which crashes when `vendor/rails` is present but works fine if it is not. I need to keep this folder deleted in my local copy so that I can work, but I don't want this deletion to ever be committed. Someone put it there for a reason.

So how do I delete this folder without it coming up in `git status` as a thousand deleted files? Obviously `.gitignore` won't work since you can't ignore files which are already tracked. Neither do any of the solutions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718372/git-ignore-deleted-files) (`git update-index --assume-unchanged`) work.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

```
 git ls-files --deleted -z | git update-index --assume-unchanged -z --stdin
```

Note that because this is an index-based operation, you cannot set directories to be ignored – only individual files. If upstream ever adds a file inside those directories, you will have to repeat the fix-up.

Comment: Ah right, directories versus files, of course. That did it - thanks!

Comment: `git ls-files --deleted -z | git update-index --assume-unchanged -z --stdin` ignores all currently deleted files.

Comment: @blinry Add this as an answer. Worked perfectly for me!

Comment: @blinry: d’oh! Far better than checking out and using find(1). I’ve updated the answer accordingly, thank you.

Comment: Yup, that’s what I meant. I’ll edit to make that clear.

Comment: How would one undo this?

Comment: Using `--no-assume-unchanged`.