# git status showing deleted files even after doing updating git index

Tags: git

I have cloned a git repo. During building, a lot of files in certain folder is showing to be deleted while doing: **git status**.

They are already in remote repo which I don't want to delete. Regarding this, I have gone through following post: 
  [Git ignore deleted files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718372/git-ignore-deleted-files)

After that I put the directory in .gitignore as well. Still while doing **git status**, I can see the same.

Comment: Do you want them deleted?

Answer (score 1):

## Having files deleted locally and not deleted in `remote`

This will not work long term. When someone else clones your repo they will get the files.

## Restoring local files

`>git checkout .` will restore the deleted files.

```
/mnt/c/git/repo666 (branchX)>git status
On branch branchX
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        deleted:    a.txt

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
/mnt/c/git/repo666 (branchX)>git checkout .
/mnt/c/git/repo666 (branchX)>git status
On branch branchX
nothing to commit, working tree clean
/mnt/c/git/repo666 (branchX)>
```

Comment: Hi @tymtam, but I don't want to restore the deleted files. I deleted them in my local. I just don't want them to get deleted in the remote. I want to ignore them from git.

Comment: Having a different setup in local and remote seems wrong. What should happen if someone clones you repo? They will get the files, is that desirable?

Answer (score 1):

If you are still seeing them in the git status, it could be due to cache.

1. Remove all files from cache, using the below command

   `git rm -r --cached .`
2. *If you want the ignoring to happen across repositories -> update gitignore*

   Post update, add files individually as per your commit

   `git add .`
3. *If you want the ignoring to happen only local repository and not at the repository level, update the exclude file: $GIT_DIR/info/exclude, instead of git ignore*

   Post update, add files individually as per your commit

   `git add .`

[Read more on ignoring files in GIT](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)