# How to prevent successive commit on specific file on git?

Tags: git

I have some configuration files to commit on GIT with default parameters.
Users can pull these files and can modify them on their local copy but they must not commit/push.

How can I achieve a similar result? the file gitignore doesn't fit my need because file must be commit only the first time

Comment: There's no way to enforce this with git. You're best bet is probably to follow the `.config.template` or `.config.defaults` pattern outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396617 . It's the most common approach to managing configuration files in source control. It's not a git specific approach.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could you use git's ["assume unchanged"](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-index.html#_using_8220_assume_unchanged_8221_bit) function? If this is set, git always assumes that the file in question has not been modified. This means that git status, git commit etc. will skip the file. Please note that the user can still push a new version of the file into your remote repo but it will take some extra work to do that.

[Here's a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655243/ignore-modified-but-not-committed-files-in-git) where the usage of "assume unchanged" was discussed more thoroughly.

Comment: But how can I force people to not suddenly commit some file? For example I'm writing integration test and everybody should edit config to match local environment. And I want to prevent these changes condif to suddenly be pushed on the server instead of templates.