# Making a file read only in Git or SourceTree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

Let's say I have a repo that looks like this:

```
Repo  
--a.txt  
--b.txt
```

Let's say I create a feature branch named `featureA` for `user A` to implement a feature. After implementing feature branch would be merged back to `master`.

Now I  want `User A` to work only with `b.txt` to implement the feature and not change `a.txt` but as far as I have seen user can change `a.txt`. So how do I restrict the user from changing `a.txt`? Also, I want `a.txt` to be in user's copy but I don't want the user to change it. Can this be done in `Git` or `SourceTree`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent successive commit on specific file on git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491751/how-to-prevent-successive-commit-on-specific-file-on-git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git's [submodule](https://github.com/blog/2104-working-with-submodules) is the one you need:

- Create a different repo, let's call it `different_repo` lol.
- Add `a.txt` to `different_repo`.
- Add `different_repo` to your current repo as a submodule.
- Remember to setting `different_repo` to read-only to some of your users.
- Cheers.