# How to tell git to ignore all further edit to a single file without removing it from the repo

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I have forked a project on github and started messing around with it on my own machine, I want to commit the changes I have made back to my fork on github but without commiting the changes I have made to the .cfg file, since this contains things like db password etc

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ignore modified (but not committed) files in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/655243/ignore-modified-but-not-committed-files-in-git)

Comment: There are probably several more duplicates around; you could search for the answer (update-index --assume-unchanged) and find all kinds of things.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Use this:

```
git update-index --skip-worktree path/file.cfg
```

And to restore:

```
git update-index --no-skip-worktree path/file.cfg
```

Lastly, if you want to list files that are marked with `skip-worktree`:

```
git ls-files -v | grep ^S | awk '{print $2}'
```

To simplify, you can make an alias for that in your `$HOME/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    ls-ignored-changes = !git ls-files -v | grep ^S | awk '{print $2}'
```

Then you can type just `git ls-ignored-changes`. It even works with auto-completion if you have the [`git-completion`](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/completion) in place (for bash, tcsh, zsh).

Comment: Heya, I've already tried that alas, then when I go to commit it's in there ready to commit. Or does that just stop it being pushed when I push?

Comment: @Gabriel Baker: that's because you already staged the file. Unstage it using `git reset path/file.cfg`.

Comment: I wish I could give you more than 1 upvote for this super useful piece of info, thanks again!

Comment: This is very wrong since Dec 2014. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28268252/1569557

Comment: @shadowbq You're right. Thank you for bringing this up. I'll investigate an alternative and update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Please use 'skip-worktree' -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630849/git-difference-between-assume-unchanged-and-skip-worktree

Comment: I did update the answer with your suggestion. Thank you!