# How to say to .gitignore: 'Ay, work!'?

Tags: git, github, gitignore

Sorry for stupid title, first. :)

Problem is very simple... `.gitignore` ignores me!

Scenario:

1. [I needed to add `application/bootstrap.php` to ignore-list. That file ignores me (still visible).](https://github.com/daGrevis/dagrevis_lv/commit/7704a875bda18222602cad5e76b09bf1aa8cb798)
2. [Then, I thought that I need to make some changes in those files. Guess what? Nothing!](https://github.com/daGrevis/dagrevis_lv/commit/a4ec271d1ce15f28f0577ac34153f3ec8a087134)
3. [Maybe I have something wrong in `.gitignore`? Lets add a newline to it. :D](https://github.com/daGrevis/dagrevis_lv/commit/df86776a9d5c747744463d807ce057043250982e)
4. [Okay, `.gitignore`! Not funny... anymore. If I'll remove this, will that make them visible? No!](https://github.com/daGrevis/dagrevis_lv/commit/eb3036f2e71a0bd8f9b197fd4afe7b0a043abb9d)

Why is that so and how can I make invisible `application/bootstrap.php` and `index.php`?

Thanks in adivce and sorry for not-so-very-boring-written-question. :D

Comment: As your bootstrap.php is commited, you cannot ignore it that way. Any tracked file cannot be ignored by gitignore. Read http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html

Comment: May I ask why you're adding the Kohana bootstrap to the ignore list? Generally it contains important things like the URL routes so it should be versioned.

Comment: @Daniel15 Hmmm... Pretty much because I don't want to update configuration (`Kohana::init()`) each time I send something to the production server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ignore already tracked files? (using Tower for Mac to work with a git repository)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999601/ignore-already-tracked-files-using-tower-for-mac-to-work-with-a-git-repository)

Comment: @daGrevis I solved that by making my URLs on dev the same as on live (the site in the root directory), setting Kohana::$environment based on the host name, and setting other stuff in init (caching/profiling) based off Kohana::$environment, so my bootstrap.php can remain identical on dev, staging and live. Means I don't need to add it to .gitignore (and don't accidentally forget to check in route changes) :) https://github.com/Daniel15/Website/blob/master/application/bootstrap.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem I believe is that `application/bootstrap.php` is a part of your repository. `.gitignore` is typically used to ignore files which are *not* part of your repository.

As the gitignore man page says:

> To ignore uncommitted changes in a file that is already tracked, use
>   `git update-index --assume-unchanged`.