# Can I remove a directory from a branch localy, but keep the directory on remote repository

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, gitlab

I am using GitLab for a remote repository for a project. One of my branches includes a large dataset of images in a directory, which needs to be available at the remote repository. But everytime I checkout from a branch, the checkout lasts forever, since it copies all the files in that directory.

Is it possible to remove the directory from a branch, so it is not included in **git ls-files**, but stays on the remote repository.

Thank you.

Comment: If you don't need it locally, try sparse checkout, https://stackoverflow.com/q/2336580/6330106.

Answer (score 0):

As ElpieKay already commented, you could use sparse checkout to tell Git explicitly which directories you want to have locally. I find [this blog post](https://briancoyner.github.io/2013/06/05/git-sparse-checkout.html) explains the feature very well.

However, personally, I find this a little messy. Also, if you have already checked out the repository, it is not a very good solution. In this case, you should use an `excludesfile`. This will allow you to ignore files as in `.gitignore` but only on your machine.

Please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55510507/2422744) to a similar question for more usage details.