# sqlite3 file add in .gitignore but still in the modified list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I ignore `*.sqlite3` file both in the project directory and the global gitignore config, but after that the sqlite3 file show in the git modified log every time.
How can I fix that?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If the file(s) is already in the repo ( ie. it is versioned ) it will continue to show as modified if you make changes to it. To make git start ignore them, first unversion the files ( using `git rm --cached` and `git commit` )

Answer (score 8):

If the file is in the repository, then ignoring it will have no effect. Remove it from the repository, or [mark it as unchanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655243/ignore-modified-but-not-committed-files-in-git).

Answer (score 4):

```bash
git rm --cached db.sqlite3
git commit
```