# Ignoring a local file is deleting the depot file

Tags: github, smartgit

I am using smartgit with github.

I have a **config.json** file on my remote github depot, with hidden passwords, at the root of the app .

I need to keep a different **config.json** file on my local depot, with real passwords.

As long as I try to ignore **config.json** locally, sometimes , it is still recorded as 'modified'
[image]

Some others times, when it finally gets ignored, by right clicking/ignore, It says  1'staged' , **config.json** finally **gets deleted from Github when pushing the commit**, I don't understand why:
[image]

THis is my **.gitignore** file :

```
.DS_Store
/config.json
config.json
node_modules
/uploads
/node_module
/dist

# local env files
.env.local
.env.*.local

# Log files
npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*

# Editor directories and files
.idea
.vscode
*.suo
*.ntvs*
*.njsproj
*.sln
*.sw?
```

My **config.json** file , with blank that I need to leave as this on Github, because **Heroku needs it** :

```
{
    "localhost_db": "mongodb://localhost:27017/",
    "mongoDb_atlas_db": "mongodb+srv://jose:x@cluster0-6kmcn.azure.mongodb.net/vue-starter-webpack?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
    "dev": false,
    "db_name": "vue-starter-webpack",
    "ftp_config": {
        "host": "ftpupload.net",
        "user": "epiz_26763901",
        "password": "x",
        "secure": false
    },
    "node_file_path": "./tmp/files/",
    "cloudinary_token": {
        "cloud_name": "ddq5asuy2",
        "api_key": "354237299578646",
        "api_secret": "x"
    },
    "logs_path": "tmp/logs/logs.txt"

}
```

Is there any workaround ? I have tried plenty of things already. What does "staged" means ? How can I keep a different version of file on github and locally ?

**EDIT :** I am trying out this command, it seems to work ! :

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged config/database.yml
```

[Ignore modified (but not committed) files in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655243/ignore-modified-but-not-committed-files-in-git/761116#761116)

Answer (score 0):

> I have a `config.json` file on my remote GitHub depot, with hidden passwords, at the root of the app.

That... is not a good practice. If that file (`config.json`) contains any sensitive information, it should *not* be added/committed, but explicitely ignored.

What you can commit is `config.json.tpl`, a template file (which is essentially what your `config.json` is right now)

From there, you could generate the right config.json file locally, and automatically on `git clone`/`git checkout`.

The generation script will:

- search the right passwords from an external secure referential (like a vault)
- replace the placeholder value in `config.json.tpl` to generate the right `config.json`

For that, do register (in a [`.gitattributes` declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309)) a **[content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571580/6309)**.

[image: smudge]
<sup>(image from "[Customizing Git - Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion)", from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/)")</sup>

The `smudge` script will generate (automatically, on `git checkout` or `git switch`) the actual `config.json` file as mentioned above.
Again, the generated actual `config.json` file remains ignored (by the `.gitignore`).

See a complete example at "[git smudge/clean filter between branches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22909620/6309)".